# How to rerun EXITing parts of an LSF job array?

Tags: cluster-computing, lsf

I submit an array of many jobs to an LSF cluster. Most run and finish in the DONE state but some may EXIT. I need a way to have only any EXITing member jobs of the array to be re-run.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been playing around with the same issues and the command:

```
brequeue -e <jobarrayid>
```

should do what you're after.  You don't need need to specify which elements should be rerun, the -e switch should pick out the EXIT'd indexes only.